# bash how to exec a command not exit?

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash

I had a command:

```
"D:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -c "git log -2"
```

but when I exec the such shell script, it print the result and **quick exit**.

I search bash refrence:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash

```
-c
```

Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument command_string, then exit.

**I do not want exit.** I want the command can pring log and hold on, so I can see it.

So what should I do?

Comment: Simply `D:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` will run an interactive Bash shell if it is correctly configured. If (as it seems) you are on Windows, there may be additional complications. I always recommend removing Windows from the equation if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options (at least):

1. Install git properly in your Windows, so you can just run `git log` directly, without the need to run bash first.
2. Run the same command you used in a Windows console.
3. Run the same command, only with another command that waits for any key to be pressed, like:

   `"D:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -c "git log -2 ; read -n1"`